# Plotting in ggplot2 - seasonal dynamics against months

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot and stuck in it :( I have a dataframe which contains monthly average values over four scenarios and looks like this

```
M     SC1    SC2   SC3    SC4    SC5
J    -18.4   9.3  -43.7  -16.1  -16.0

F    -17.9  -8.8  -46.3  -17.2  14.1
```

M - is month and SC* are values for different scenarios.
To use those for ggplot I have converted it into a "long" datafarme using `melt()`. The result looks like this

```
M   variable    value
J   SC1     -18.4
F   SC1     -17.98
M   SC1     -28.23
A   SC1     -36.98
M   SC1     -23.82
J   SC1     -26.86
J   SC1     -21.76
A   SC1     -19.99
S   SC1     -19.91
O   SC1     -26.79
N   SC1     -35.94
D   SC1     -23.76
J   SC2       9.31
F   SC2      -8.84
```

Now I'd like to plot seasonal dynamics for each scenario as lines (which is simple if I do it with just `plot()` and a "wide" datafarame).

However when I write in `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(data=x_long, aes(x=M, y=value, group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

I get a mess of lines. I guess that might be because of absence of a proper date? Also the values on y are not in order - not as a sequence from -40 to +18, but just all the values randomly I have in value column.

I have tried to give the scenarios one by one:

```
ggplot(data=x_long, aes(x=M))+
  geom_line(aes(y=value,group=SC1))
```

It claims there is no SC1 object..

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points you need to fix to get what you want:

- in `aes` the names you are using are matched to column names from your `data.frame`. That's why `group=SC1` does not work
- the values of `y` correspond to the values of `x` and they are not random. If you see at the x-axis the names of the months are in alphabetical order. So `ggplot` took all month initials put them in order and plotted the result after grouping according to `variable`.

Now what you want to do is the following:

You want each month to have unique name, e.g. Jan, Feb, etc., and then you want to order them yourself.

```
x_long$M <- factor(x_long$M, levels = month.abb)

ggplot(data=x_long, aes(x = M, y = value, group = variable, col = variable)) +
geom_line()
```

[image]

Hope this helps,
alex

Comment: For the levels you can use the built-in `month.abb`.

Comment: No problem. If your question is answered, consider accepting it by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the question.